# Imaging/graphics apps leave ghost processes

Tags: windows-7, process

### Summary

Recently put a clean install of Windows 7 x64 on a laptop. Now all imaging-related apps seem to hang on close, approx. one time out of every 10 runs.

### Problem details

I close an imaging app (Photoshop CS5 x64, Photoshop CS5 x32, or Irfanview 4.30). Approximately one out of ten times, the app window will close, but the process will remain running, visible in the Processes tab of the Task Manager.

These processes use minimal CPU ( < 1% ) and does not interfere with future instances of the application (Photoshop or Irfanview can be opened again while the hung process is present).

This does not happen with any other apps than those mentioned above.

### Update

For Irfanview, this will happen 100% of the time if the Save for Web plugin is used, and then the program is closed via the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

### Update 2

Found a [related topic here](http://irfanview-forum.de/archive/index.php/t-137.html), although no solution was found.

### Update 3

This behavior does not appear on Windows XP. Tested with clean installs of Windows 7 x64 SP1 Ultimate, Windows XP SP3 Pro and Windows XP 64-bit SP2.

Comment: What are the hardware specs. for the laptop?

Comment: I think I saw that with another program, in 7, but I am still clinging to XP. I fired up the resource monitor to check for all I/O it might be doing. that is all i remember :-( --Interested.

Comment: @Unsigned: What plugin is the "Save for Web Plugin"? I'm having trouble finding such a plugin to try this...

Answer (score 2):

#### It's likely just a bug.

Honestly, I think it's just a bug. The only "solution" would be provided by the developers.

File a bug report if you're in the mood (*especially* consider this if you can come up with instructions for reproducing the problem).

Comment: @Unsigned: It's also appeared in other programs I've seen, and programs *I've written*. It's an **easy bug** to make, especially if your program is multithreaded or does anything in the background. There's nothing unusual about it.

Comment: @Unsigned: There could be a million reasons, from the application calling a different function on Windows, to Windows sending a different message to the program in the newer version. It's really hard to say -- but the point is that Windows has a gazillion different messages that it sends to applications (and vice-versa), so it's really difficult to anticipate all the things that can happen. But really there's no reason other than a bug (very likely in the application, or possibly -- but unlikely -- in Windows). Likely nothing other than the source code/debug symbols can help you figure it out.

Comment: @Unsigned: Yeah, the bug is quite often that it isn't exiting the message loop, but it's the reason that makes each bug different. Are there any [DWM-related](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729170.aspx) messages being sent? (Spy++ might be helpful, if you're not using it already.) Maybe it's related to one of those? I'll see if I can reproduce the problem and figure it out, though I doubt I can.

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest drivers, especially video and chipset, and make sure your apps are patched to their latest versions as well.