# Windows 7 - Intermittently processes will not close when the app closes

Tags: windows, process

I have a user I am supporting who has the strangest issue. There are 2 problem applications, Word 2010 and a scanning program called ScandallPro. Intermittently (and at least once a day), she will close an app and the underlying process will not close. Both Word 2010 and this scanning software have all the latest updates.

There is another user who has the same software that does not have this problem, and has identical hardware. I have formatted and rebuilt the computer for the user who is having the problems. After the rebuild, the machine was fine for a day but the scanning software continues to intermittently keep the process running even after it is closed. This is a problem because she cannot open a new instance of it while the process is still running.

There is a boatload of line of business software on this machine, all of which she needs. I believe the Word 2010 issue is due to a misbehaving add-in (there are 2 add-ins, neither of which seem stable), and I think my best bet is to work with the add-in vendor on it. The scanning program staying open is isolated to this 1 user. The only difference between her machine and the other user is that she has Quickbooks, RoboForm, and Adobe Acrobat X Pro.

Any ideas of what can be causing this, or other diagnostic steps to try?

Comment: It is interesting that you have one user machine that does, and one does not using similar software.  See also similar http://superuser.com/questions/369273/imaging-graphics-apps-leave-ghost-processes